# Query objects by their key

Tags: php, mongodb, database-design

The data I want to save in my MongoDB looks like this:

```
{
    "2": {
        "3": "some value",
        "7": "some value",
        ...
    },
    "8": {
        "20": "some value",
        "24": "some value",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I would like to query "8" and get

```
{
    "20": "some value",
    "24": "some value",
    ...
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to query the objects by their keys in PHP, or do I have to change the data structure to something like below and use `$collection->find( [ 'id' => '8'] );`?

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data" {
            "3": "some value",
            "7": "some value",
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "data" {
            "20": "some value",
            "24": "some value",
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
]
```

Comment: Possible? Yes. **Practical?** ***NO***. Seems someone might have already given you some advice on structure, so instead of asking for opinions here I suggest you do some research on why that was the advice as well as understanding databases in general. Databases find things fast on "values" and not "keys". Yes this is the oposite of what you may have been taught about using keys in your data structures, but suffice to say there's cleverness going on there which is basically doing that "fast lookup" thing for you. Use the value form with a database unless it's documentation says otherwise.

Comment: @JayBlanchard There's nothing that's not working. The question is rather about database design.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your response. I've been working with JSON in JS where key-based search is faster so that's why the first solution was kind of intuitive for me but it makes sense what you wrote about databases. That's all I wanted, no full solution, no PHP code :)